# Should roaming between Asus AiMesh routers work?

Tags: router, mesh-networking

I bought three Asus RT-AC66U routers that should support something called AiMesh. Otherwise the setup works ok but roaming between the wifi routers always break the connection.

If I start a WhatsApp video call in the study and move to the center of the house, the call will break and say something like "trying to reconnect", which it never does, however. The same goes for MS Teams. If I need to move my laptop during a meeting, Teams will disconnect and I need to restart the meeting.

I have setup one router as the main router, connected to the fiber terminal, and the other two are connected by ethernet cable (ethernet backhaul) to the primary router. The is a setting in the routers called Roaming assistant which is enabled.

The setup looks like this:

[image]

In the Asus config it looks like this:

[image]

Should roaming be possible and if so, how can I fix the roaming problem?

Comment: Roaming assist just means the router is intentionally disconnecting clients to make them seek a better AP.

Comment: Would I be better off disabling that setting?